# Righ click doesn't work on an Elantech touchpad

Tags: touchpad

Neither two nor three finger click. Everything else works perfectly (two finger scroll, dragging etc.). The core is 3.2.0.25.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Normally, Elantech touchpad works out of the box in Ubuntu 12.04 (For kernel 3.3-rc5 on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS Elantech drivers is working very good).

Changes made in 3.2 :

- The whole pad is the left button, there is thus no right button. However a revision to the Synaptics driver restores click-pad functionality. See [here](http://www.theorangenotebook.com/2012/02/call-for-testing-clickpad.html) for the Ubuntu package and instructions.
- click and drag is done by clicking anywhere on the pad and moving the finger.
- Right mouse is available as two-finger tap.
- Middle button is available as three finger tap.

You can also use synclient to setup the touchpad. Here is an example script from Aurélien Jacobs and Marcus Möller. You can save it as `~/bin/touchpad_settings` and add it as Unity startup script using gnome-session-properties:

```
# higher sensitivity
synclient FingerLow=9 FingerHigh=12

# faster speed and acceleration
synclient MinSpeed=1.5 MaxSpeed=3.5 AccelFactor=0.1

# 2 fingers scroll (can be also enabled in System Settings)
synclient VertTwoFingerScroll=1 HorizTwoFingerScroll=1

# faster coasting
synclient CoastingSpeed=10

# enable tap to click (2 fingers for middle click, 3 fingers for right click)
synclient TapButton1=1 TapButton2=3 TapButton3=2

# continue dragging movement when reaching the edge of the touchpad
synclient EdgeMotionMinZ=30 EdgeMotionMaxZ=40 EdgeMotionMinSpeed=100 EdgeMotionMaxSpeed=400
```

Comment: Worked. I thought it was expecting two-finger hard click - but it just needs a slight two-fingers touch (or three-fingers touch).

Answer (score 1):

This fixed the right click button properly https://github.com/avernois/enable-elantech-on-ubuntu

Tested on Asus N56VZ

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.